# Запятая перед тире: нужна?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

«Иногда то, что вы видели только в черном цвете(,) — просто сложное сочетание красок».
Нужна ли запятая и почему, если да?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужна. см. Артем Луговой.

> То есть запятая перед тире нужна во всех предложениях, где есть союз с
>   «что», как я поняла?

Нет.
Во-первых, "что" здесь не союз, а союзное слово. И такое союзное слово может быть любым - из числа грамматически возможных.

Во-вторых, конечно же не во всех, а только тогда, когда это определяется грамматикой. В данном случае имеем "стык" запятой, закрывающей придаточное и тире, поставленного по другим мотивам (тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженными существительными). Если такого стыка нет, то запятой перед тире может и не быть - или она ставится по другим мотивам. 
В-третьих, не стоит изобретать какие-то частные "правила", когда есть одно общее. ***Если тире и запятая ставятся по разным мотивам, то первое не поглощает вторую.*** 
Правда, тут могут быть дискуссионные случаи, но в целом правило это почти абсолютное.

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь, кажется, стало яснее. :)

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна: она закрывает придаточное с союзом "что". Тире *не отменяет* её.

Comment: То есть запятая перед тире нужна во всех предложениях, где есть союз с «что», как я поняла?